# What is the mechanism of Salkowski reaction of сholesterols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, analytical-chemistry, lipids

I recently came across the Salkowski reaction of cholesterols. Cholesterol in chloroform is treated with concentrated sulfuric acid. A positive test exhibits two distinct layers, the upper chloroform layer gets a red to violet colour, while the lower sulfuric acid layer exhibits a greenish glow.

1. The chemistry behind the reaction is dehydration using $\ce{H2SO4},$ forming cholestadiene.

   [image: dehydration of сholesterol]
2. In the second step, the cholestadiene undergoes dimerization.

   [image: dimerization of cholestadiene]
3. In the last step, the cholestadiene undergoes sulfonation at the 7,7' position. (I believe I drew the correct structure)

   [image: sulfonation of cholestadiene]

However, I couldn't find a *valid mechanism* for the second and the third steps (dimerization and sulfonation). Can someone explain the mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this mechanism looks very "hand-wavey" to me, possibly just to make it a little easier to follow. [This paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/000456329202900601) makes me think it might go through a carbonation intermediate.

Comment: @SendersReagent: However, [this article](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cpb1958/12/12/12_12_1500/_pdf) before yours has claimed the isolation of final dimer without sulfonic acid groups under Zac-Henry conditions.

Comment: I think [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/0039-128X(78)90110-1) may give you the insight for given chemical formations.

Answer (score 4):

The mechanism of dimerization is now clear, Thanks to Mathew Mahindratne.
Ref.[Yoshihisa, *et.al*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0039-128X(78)90110-1)

There are two different isomers of Cholestadiene present, namely 3,5 Cholestadiene **[ I ]**, and 2,4 cholestdiene **[ IV ]**. The plausible mechanism of their formation is shown below. They can undergo dimerization to yield [ II ] & [III].

[image: Mechanism of formation of cholestadiene isomers]

Dimer [ II ] was formed from two pathways, which were the conversion of the dimer [ III ] and the dimerization of  [I]  (3,5-cholestadiene).

The dimer [ III ] was formed from [ IV ] (2,4-cholestadiene).

The mechanism of their formation is shown below.
[image]

The formation of the dimer [ II ] and/or the dimer [ III ] varies with the kind of acids employed.
Using a **Bronsted acid** medium results in the formation of **[ II ]**.
For eg: In presence of Trichloroacetic acid and hydrochloric acid (10:1 ratio), dimer [ II ] was obtained.

Using a **Lewis acid** results in the formation of **[ III ]**. For eg: *Zinc chloride* and *Acetyl chloride* (Tschugaeff reaction),
*Antimony trichloride* and *Acetyl chloride*,
*Ferric chloride* and *Sulfuric acid* (Zak-Henly reaction),
*Ferric chloride*, *Perchloric acid*, and *Phosphoric acid* results in the formation of [ III ].

If the solution contains both **Bronsted and Lewis acid**s, then a **mixture** **of products** is formed.

Eg: Both [ II ] and [ III ] are formed from the reactions with

1. Sulfuric acid and Acetic anhydride (Liebermann-Burchard reaction)
2. sulfuric acid (Salkowski reaction)
3. Trichloroacetic acid-SbCl3

Since sulfuric acid, having both Bronsted and Lewis acid character is used in our reaction, a mixture of products will be formed.
Ps: All Bronsted acids are Lewis acids, but not vice versa.

However, the third step (Sulfonation) needs further explanation.